# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have little problem when i want to insert image into form, the code work on other form but in this form it not work with  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null 
here is my code
javascript :

```
function edit(ids,idserv,namaproj,linkproj,img){
//alert(ids+" "+idserv+" "+namaproj+" "+linkproj+" "+img);
document.getElementById('ids').value=ids;
document.getElementById('ns').value=namaproj;
document.getElementById('kt').value=linkproj;
document.getElementById('link').value=idserv;
document.getElementById('img1').src="./img/"+img;

document.getElementById("myFormedit").style.display = "block";}
```

form :

```
   <form action="tservices" method = "POST" class="form-container" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h1>Edit Services</h1>
<input type="text" id="ids" name="ids" hidden>
<label><b>Nama Project</b></label>
<input type="text" name = "nama" id="ns"  required>
<label>Link Project</label>
<input type="text" name = "ket" id="kt" required>
    <label><b>Service</b></label>
<select name="tujuan" id="link">
<?php
$sartikel = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from services");
$nartikel = mysqli_num_rows($sartikel);
for($i=1;$i<=$nartikel;$i++){
    $r = mysqli_fetch_array($sartikel);
    $id = $r[0];
    $judul = $r[1];
    $isi = $r[2];
    $tgl = $r[3];
    $gmbr = $r[4];
    $st = $r[5];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $judul; ?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
<h3>Foto Project</h3>
<img id="img1" height="150" width="150" ><br>
<input class="w3-input" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile2(event)" name="fd">

</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn"name="button" value="edit">Ubah</button>
<button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeFormedit()">Tutup</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('img1')` returns `null` which tells you that there's no element with the id `img1` in the DOM when this line of your script is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your img tag is inside the select tag so your javascript is not recognizing the element with id 'img' and showing and the TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the script tag or the script itself if it is in the html file is executed after the DOM is rendered, therefore check if the script is located under the htlm that you showed.

Comment: i got the problem already ,
the img tag was in the select tag thanks for the help

Comment: Even so getElementById shoul work, you sure there is no other changes that you made?